# How to fg a process suspended before starting tmux inside the new tmux session?

Tags: bash, display, process, tmux

How to 1. suspend a process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, 2. start `tmux` and 3. `fg` (or `bg`) the suspended process?

```
$ find / 
[.....]
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 10
$ tmux
$ fg
-bash: fg: current: no such job
```

It would of course be possible to `bg` before starting tmux but then the tmux session ends up being garbled with the process output.

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require installing software.

Answer (score 1):

Try [reptyr: Resume running processes in screen or tmux](http://www.rvdh.de/2014/03/26/reptyr-resume-running-processes-in-screen-or-tmux/)